# Trigger e-Invoice via API

Tags: invoice, xero-api, peppol

We create invoices in Xero using Custom Connector for a number of customers, depending on customer requirements after creating the invoice we either trigger the email of the invoice (as per https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices/#emailing-an-invoice) or bring a copy of the invoice PDF back to the customers other system for sending from there.

Now that e-Invoicing has been introduced in NZ our customers want to start sending invoices as eInvoices.  Can this be achieved by the API?

We are using https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/ - so version 2.0 of the API, which is the current version as far as we can tell.  Our interpretation is that it doesn't seem to be supported in the current API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xero Dev support confirmed this can't be done by API so I've added a suggestion to the Xero User Voice forum - if you want to trigger e-Invoices via Xero API then vote for it here:

https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-accounting-api/suggestions/46554133-trigger-e-invoice-via-api